ls changes behaviour if stdout redirected?
I found this:
$ ls /mnt/pid_oper/ ; echo $?
ls: cannot access '/mnt/pid_oper/Trans': No such file or directory
Trans
1
$ ls /mnt/pid_oper/ > /dev/null; echo $?
0

Does the redirect changes the return code?
Obviousely not:
$ $(exit 138) ; echo $?
138
$ $(exit 138) > /dev/null; echo $?
138

This bug (?) got me for half a day.
Per accident, I found this:
$ ls /mnt/pid_oper/ > /dev/null; echo $?
0
$ ls -l /mnt/pid_oper/ > /dev/null; echo $?
ls: cannot access '/mnt/pid_oper/Trans': No such file or directory
1

So, -l does also change the behaviour??
Any explanations on this?
OS: RHEL 8.1
Background: I've used this command to check stalled mounts, that looks like this:
d?????????? ? ?    ?     ?            ? Trans


This definitely appears to be a bug. What is the mount type of the stalled mount? I'd like to try to reproduce it. In any case, ls exit code behaviour should be consistent despite the stdout file type.

My theory would be that you have have ls using color mode by default, probably by having set up an alias to ls --color=auto or something similar. (You could check with type ls)
In color mode it has to stat the things in order to pick the colors (directory, executable, etc...), much like it would otherwise need with -l to actually print that information in itself.
And with auto mode, it only does colors for terminal output, hence changing behavior with redirected output.

Wow... this is an answer! Thanks!
